# Skip first element of an array in Golang

Tags: go

I have the following code segments

```
for _, val := range Arr {
    // something have to do with val
}
```

In **Arr** , there might be more than 1 elements. I want to skip the first element of **Arr** and continue the loop from the second element.

For example if **Arr** contains {1,2,3,4}. With the query I just want to take {2,3,4}.

Is there a way to do that with the range query ?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Yes. Use this

```
for _, val := range Arr[1:] {
// something to do with val
}
```

Or in case you can get empty slice:

```
for i := 1; i < len(Arr); i++ {
// something to do with Arr[i]
}
```

Comment: @T.Claverie Good catch. I edited it. I was using len(Arr) Forgot to edit out the other part.

Comment: It's enough the first version. It's more idiomatic and in the Go way.

Comment: and you should probably never name a variable "l" (lower case L) as it looks too much like a "1" (one) in most fonts.   When I read your second example, I thought it said Arr[1:1] (as in, a zero length slice starting at the second position)

Comment: @DavidBudworth Thanks, and will follow that advice.

Comment: Doesn't work on an empty slice `runtime error: slice bounds out of range`. See T. Claverie's answer.

Answer (score 9):

Use a standard `for` loop or the slice operator:

```
for _, val := range Arr[1:] {
    // Do something
}

// Or
for i := 1; i < len(Arr); i++ {
    val = Arr[i]
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: The `for i := 1; i < ...` nicely handles empty slices, too, which other answers don't offer.

Comment: Isn't there a way to merge both answers? (they are the same and are just splitting the vote...)

Answer (score 2):

convert to slice then skip first element(with the range query):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    Arr := [...]int{1, 2, 3, 4}
    for _, val := range Arr[1:] {
        fmt.Println(val)
    }
}
```

using index to skip first element(with the range query):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    Arr := [...]int{1, 2, 3, 4}
    for i, val := range Arr {
        if i == 0 {
            continue
        }
        fmt.Println(val)
    }
}
```

using one bool var to skip first element(with the range query):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    Arr := [...]int{1, 2, 3, 4}
    first := true
    for _, val := range Arr {
        if first {
            first = false
            continue
        }
        fmt.Println(val)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you what to do something different with the first value, you can do this:

```
for i, val := range Arr {
   if i == 0 {
       //Ignore or do something with first val   
   }else{
       // something have to do with val
   }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
for _, val := range Arr[len(Arr)-(len(Arr)-1):] {
    // something have to do with val
}
```

Instead use this

```
for _, val := range Arr[1:] {
    // something have to do with val
}
```

Comment: Heh! Downvoted, since `len(Arr)-(len(Arr)-1) = 1` (do the math!) so you could pretty much save yourself two function calls (who knows, possibly the Go compiler catches that), and then your answer would be the same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/37429331/1035977 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/37429317/1035977